# iOS 14 Widget Detect System Theme Change

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

I construct my widget with a programmatically generated UIImage in *getTimeline*.

So I need to know in *getTimeline* if the iOS theme is either Light or Dark.

I know how to do that in a ViewController with `traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark`, but how can I do it in a Widget?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although Widget views are static, you may still detect `@Environment(\.colorScheme)`.

Here is a simple demo:

```
struct WidgetEntryView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var bgColor: some View {
        colorScheme == .dark ? Color.red : Color.orange
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            bgColor
            Text(entry.date, style: .time)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note that when the system color scheme changes:

- only your View is redrawn, the `getTimeline` function is not called again
- the default colors change automatically when the system color scheme changes

---

<sub>Here is a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pawello2222/WidgetExamples#environment-widget) with different Widget examples including the Environment Widget.</sub>

Comment: Thanks but how do I know the iOS theme color in getTimeline so that I can render my image properly?

Comment: @Cosmin Why can't you create it in your view? In `getTimeline` just pass the data to your Entry and in the View create an image depending on the current color scheme.

Comment: @Cosmin I ended up creating two images for each timeline entry and then picked the right one from the view **Image(uiImage: colorScheme == .dark ? entry.darkImage : entry.lightImage)**