# Update Widget when appearance changes

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

I would need to know if any of you know a system in SwiftUI to update a Widget when the appearance changes from `light` mode to `dark` mode and vice versa.

I can change text and images but I use a method to display a screenshot of a map and I should run it every time the appearance changes to get the correct map color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create two screenshots (one per theme) and pass it in the entry:

```
struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let mapScreenshots: [ColorScheme: Image]
}
```

```
struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    ...

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<SimpleEntry>) -> Void) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(
            date: Date(),
            mapScreenshots: [
                // replace with actual map screenshots
                .dark: Image(systemName: "plus"),
                .light: Image(systemName: "minus"),
            ]
        )
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .never)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}
```

2. Use `@Environment(\.colorScheme)` to react to theme changes:

```
struct WidgetEntryView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        if let screenshot = entry.mapScreenshots[colorScheme] {
            screenshot
        }
    }
}
```

- [iOS 14 Widget Detect System Theme Change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64182738/8697793)

Comment: Thanks @pawello2222 

Great idea , I had not thought about it ...
Only one problem: I use the MKMapSnapshotter method to produce the screenshot, but I can't define the map appearance.
In the documentation I found an Instance Property "appearance" but it is an NSAppearance property and so I cannot use it in iOS ...
Do you have any idea ?

Comment: let traitCollectionLight = UITraitCollection.init(userInterfaceStyle: UIUserInterfaceStyle.light)

Comment: mapSnapshotOptions.traitCollection = traitCollectionLight