# iOS 14 widget - getTimeline - detect light and dark mode

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

In my iOS14 widget, I need to detect light or dark mode of the system, because based on this, I do different operations during timeline creation.

I have tried

```
struct WidgetProvider: IntentTimelineProvider {

    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    func getTimeline(
       for configuration: MyConfigurationIntent,
       in context: Context,
       completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> Void
    ) {
        //colorScheme is never equal to .dark
    }
}
```

If I use  `let darkMode = UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark` instead of `colorScheme`, it works, but only once. If I change mode and widget reloads, it is still using the old color mode.

How to detect the mode correctly?

Comment: I think your widgets may not be reloading. Sorry if this is incorrect, I am new to widgets, but I'm pretty sure that they reload at a frequency that is very lengthy. You may want to look at how you can make the widget reload every time it appears.

Comment: I know, but even if the reload is trigerred, they remain incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

First, the `@Environment` variables can be used in SwiftUI Views only. You can't use them in the `IntentTimelineProvider`.

Then, you correctly tried an alternative method for `colorScheme` detection:

```
let darkMode = UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark
```

The catch is that when you change the appearance, the entries (and timeline itself) are **not** regenerated. Only the *view* is redrawn.

The best possibility is to use `@Environment(\.colorScheme)` directly in the view. See this answer:

- [Update Widget when appearance changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64635723/8697793)

If you really need to create *color-scheme-dependent* variables in the timeline, I suggest you create them for both color schemes and display conditionally in the view based on `@Environment(\.colorScheme)`.

Comment: I know it is not called when mode changes. However, it is not updated even when getTimeline is called after timeout.

Comment: @MartinPerry Seems like `UITraitCollection` doesn't work in widgets (maybe because it's it's from UIKit). This means you need to use `@Environment(\.colorScheme)` in a view.